# javascript create object using multiple variables for multiple property name

Tags: javascript, json

how can i create object using multiple variables for multiple property name.

I am trying to create multiple versions of an object which has an init function. I have tried using the javascript 'new' function but in this case that does not work and the console notifies me this is because it is not a function. See the code for a clearer description of what I am trying to do.

```
for (a=1;a<=5;a++)
        {
            json.name={};
            json.name[a]={};
            for (b=1;b<11;b++)
            {
                json.name[a][b]={};
                json.name[a][b]=$("input#c"+b+"r"+a).val();
            } 
            //json.name.1.3  = the value from the input
```

Comment: FYI the line: `json.name[a][b]={};` is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the fact you keep writing over the variable in the loop.

Move `json.name={};` outside the for loop.

```
var a, b, json;
json.name = {};
for (a=1; a<=5; a++) {
    json.name[a] = {};
    for (b=1; b<11; b++) {
        json.name[a][b] = $("input#c"+b+"r"+a).val();
    }
}
```

It also seems weird you are using objects and not arrays and that you are starting at one and not zero.